# Getting coordinates of the boundary around a colored shape in Python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, coordinates

I have an image that contains a blue shape inside of it. I want to get the coordinates (x,y) in an array format of the pixels around the shape. I have attached a sampled image. I want to get the coordinates of the pixels that border the blue shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to process your new image using cv2.inRange() in HSV colorspace to threshold the blue region.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('blue_blob.png')

# convert to hsv color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# set lower and upper bounds on blue color
lower = (0,90,200)
upper = (150,255,255)

# threshold and invert so hexagon is white on black background
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper);

# get contours
result = np.zeros_like(img)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
cntr = contours[0]
cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), 1)

# print number of points along contour
print('number of points: ',len(cntr))

print('')

# list contour points
for pt in cntr:
    print(pt)

# save resulting images
cv2.imwrite('blue_blob_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('blue_blob_contour.png',result) 

# show thresh and contour   
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Contour image:

[image]

Coordinates:

```
number of points:  149

[[61 26]]
[[60 27]]
[[59 27]]
[[58 28]]
[[57 28]]
[[57 29]]
[[56 30]]
[[55 30]]
[[55 31]]
[[54 32]]
[[53 32]]
[[53 33]]
[[52 34]]
[[51 34]]
[[51 35]]
[[52 35]]
[[53 36]]
[[53 37]]
[[53 38]]
[[53 39]]
[[53 40]]
[[53 41]]
[[53 42]]
[[53 43]]
[[53 44]]
[[53 45]]
[[54 45]]
[[55 46]]
[[55 47]]
[[55 48]]
[[55 49]]
[[55 50]]
[[55 51]]
[[55 52]]
[[55 53]]
[[55 54]]
[[56 55]]
[[57 56]]
[[57 57]]
[[57 58]]
[[57 59]]
[[57 60]]
[[57 61]]
[[57 62]]
[[58 61]]
[[59 62]]
[[59 63]]
[[59 64]]
[[59 65]]
[[59 66]]
[[59 67]]
[[60 67]]
[[61 68]]
[[61 69]]
[[61 70]]
[[61 71]]
[[62 72]]
[[63 73]]
[[63 74]]
[[63 75]]
[[63 76]]
[[63 77]]
[[64 77]]
[[65 78]]
[[64 79]]
[[65 80]]
[[65 81]]
[[65 82]]
[[65 83]]
[[66 83]]
[[67 83]]
[[68 83]]
[[69 83]]
[[70 83]]
[[71 83]]
[[72 83]]
[[72 82]]
[[73 81]]
[[74 81]]
[[75 81]]
[[76 81]]
[[76 80]]
[[76 79]]
[[76 78]]
[[76 77]]
[[76 76]]
[[76 75]]
[[76 74]]
[[77 73]]
[[78 73]]
[[78 72]]
[[78 71]]
[[78 70]]
[[78 69]]
[[78 68]]
[[78 67]]
[[78 66]]
[[78 65]]
[[78 64]]
[[78 63]]
[[78 62]]
[[78 61]]
[[78 60]]
[[78 59]]
[[78 58]]
[[78 57]]
[[78 56]]
[[78 55]]
[[78 54]]
[[78 53]]
[[78 52]]
[[78 51]]
[[78 50]]
[[78 49]]
[[78 48]]
[[78 47]]
[[78 46]]
[[77 46]]
[[76 45]]
[[76 44]]
[[76 43]]
[[76 42]]
[[76 41]]
[[76 40]]
[[76 39]]
[[76 38]]
[[76 37]]
[[75 37]]
[[74 36]]
[[74 35]]
[[74 34]]
[[74 33]]
[[74 32]]
[[73 32]]
[[72 31]]
[[72 30]]
[[71 30]]
[[70 30]]
[[69 30]]
[[68 29]]
[[68 28]]
[[68 27]]
[[68 26]]
[[67 26]]
[[66 26]]
[[65 26]]
[[64 26]]
[[63 26]]
[[62 26]]
```

Note: If the threshold leaves holes or extraneous white spots, then you should use -morphology close and open to clean it up. Also see

[cv2.inRange()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981)

and

[cv2.morphologyEx()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f)

Comment: This is great! For some images, however, it does not work. For example, for some images, only 1 point is returned for some reason. I tried playing around with the threshold values itself, but I still wasn't able to solve the issue. Do you know what the fix could possibly be?

Comment: I suspect you have a different color region. If that is the case, you need to set the lower and upper color values appropriate to your color. Pick a BGR color from the region that is representative. Then transform it to HSV. Then subtract some from each value for the lower and add a similar amount to it for the upper.

Comment: No, I only have one blue mask there. Still not sure why that is the case

Comment: Are using the same input as originally presented or a new image? If a new image, please post a link to it so that I can see what might be the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to list the coordinates of every pixel along the border using Python/OpenCV. (I assume when you said pixel, you wanted that and not just the vertices of the polygon)

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Otsu threshold and invert
- Find the external contour
- List the contour points

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('blue_hexagon.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold and invert so hexagon is white on black background
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = 255 - thresh

# get contours
result = np.zeros_like(img)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
cntr = contours[0]
cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), 1)

# print number of points along contour
print('number of points: ',len(cntr))

print('')

# list contour points
for pt in cntr:
    print(pt)

# save resulting images
cv2.imwrite('blue_hexagon_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('blue_hexagon_contour.png',result)  

# show thresh and contour   
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Contour image:

[image]

Textual Information:

```
number of points:  608

[[57 15]]
[[56 16]]
[[55 17]]
[[55 18]]
[[54 19]]
[[54 20]]
[[53 21]]
[[52 22]]
[[52 23]]
[[51 24]]
[[51 25]]
[[50 26]]
[[49 27]]
[[49 28]]
[[48 29]]
[[48 30]]
[[47 31]]
[[47 32]]
[[46 33]]
[[45 34]]
[[45 35]]
[[44 36]]
[[44 37]]
[[43 38]]
[[42 39]]
[[42 40]]
[[41 41]]
[[41 42]]
[[40 43]]
[[40 44]]
[[39 45]]
[[38 46]]
[[38 47]]
[[37 48]]
[[37 49]]
[[36 50]]
[[35 51]]
[[35 52]]
[[34 53]]
[[34 54]]
[[33 55]]
[[33 56]]
[[32 57]]
[[31 58]]
[[31 59]]
[[30 60]]
[[30 61]]
[[29 62]]
[[29 63]]
[[28 64]]
[[27 65]]
[[27 66]]
[[26 67]]
[[26 68]]
[[25 69]]
[[25 70]]
[[24 71]]
[[23 72]]
[[23 73]]
[[22 74]]
[[22 75]]
[[21 76]]
[[20 77]]
[[20 78]]
[[19 79]]
[[19 80]]
[[18 81]]
[[18 82]]
[[17 83]]
[[17 84]]
[[16 85]]
[[15 86]]
[[15 87]]
[[14 88]]
[[14 89]]
[[13 90]]
[[12 91]]
[[12 92]]
[[11 93]]
[[11 94]]
[[10 95]]
[[10 96]]
[[ 9 97]]
[[ 8 98]]
[[ 8 99]]
[[  7 100]]
[[  7 101]]
[[  6 102]]
[[  6 103]]
[[  5 104]]
[[  4 105]]
[[  4 106]]
[[  3 107]]
[[  3 108]]
[[  2 109]]
[[  2 110]]
[[  1 111]]
[[  1 112]]
[[  1 113]]
[[  2 114]]
[[  2 115]]
[[  3 116]]
[[  3 117]]
[[  4 118]]
[[  4 119]]
[[  5 120]]
[[  5 121]]
[[  6 122]]
[[  7 123]]
[[  7 124]]
[[  8 125]]
[[  8 126]]
[[  9 127]]
[[ 10 128]]
[[ 10 129]]
[[ 11 130]]
[[ 11 131]]
[[ 12 132]]
[[ 12 133]]
[[ 13 134]]
[[ 14 135]]
[[ 14 136]]
[[ 15 137]]
[[ 15 138]]
[[ 16 139]]
[[ 16 140]]
[[ 17 141]]
[[ 18 142]]
[[ 18 143]]
[[ 19 144]]
[[ 19 145]]
[[ 20 146]]
[[ 20 147]]
[[ 21 148]]
[[ 22 149]]
[[ 22 150]]
[[ 23 151]]
[[ 23 152]]
[[ 24 153]]
[[ 25 154]]
[[ 25 155]]
[[ 26 156]]
[[ 26 157]]
[[ 27 158]]
[[ 27 159]]
[[ 28 160]]
[[ 29 161]]
[[ 29 162]]
[[ 30 163]]
[[ 30 164]]
[[ 31 165]]
[[ 31 166]]
[[ 32 167]]
[[ 33 168]]
[[ 33 169]]
[[ 34 170]]
[[ 34 171]]
[[ 35 172]]
[[ 35 173]]
[[ 36 174]]
[[ 37 175]]
[[ 37 176]]
[[ 38 177]]
[[ 38 178]]
[[ 39 179]]
[[ 40 180]]
[[ 40 181]]
[[ 41 182]]
[[ 41 183]]
[[ 42 184]]
[[ 42 185]]
[[ 43 186]]
[[ 44 187]]
[[ 44 188]]
[[ 45 189]]
[[ 45 190]]
[[ 46 191]]
[[ 47 192]]
[[ 47 193]]
[[ 48 194]]
[[ 48 195]]
[[ 49 196]]
[[ 49 197]]
[[ 50 198]]
[[ 50 199]]
[[ 51 200]]
[[ 52 201]]
[[ 52 202]]
[[ 53 203]]
[[ 53 204]]
[[ 54 205]]
[[ 55 206]]
[[ 55 207]]
[[ 56 208]]
[[ 57 209]]
[[ 58 209]]
[[ 59 209]]
[[ 60 209]]
[[ 61 209]]
[[ 62 209]]
[[ 63 209]]
[[ 64 209]]
[[ 65 209]]
[[ 66 209]]
[[ 67 209]]
[[ 68 209]]
[[ 69 209]]
[[ 70 209]]
[[ 71 209]]
[[ 72 209]]
[[ 73 209]]
[[ 74 209]]
[[ 75 209]]
[[ 76 209]]
[[ 77 209]]
[[ 78 209]]
[[ 79 209]]
[[ 80 209]]
[[ 81 209]]
[[ 82 209]]
[[ 83 209]]
[[ 84 209]]
[[ 85 209]]
[[ 86 209]]
[[ 87 209]]
[[ 88 209]]
[[ 89 209]]
[[ 90 209]]
[[ 91 209]]
[[ 92 209]]
[[ 93 209]]
[[ 94 209]]
[[ 95 209]]
[[ 96 209]]
[[ 97 209]]
[[ 98 209]]
[[ 99 209]]
[[100 209]]
[[101 209]]
[[102 209]]
[[103 209]]
[[104 209]]
[[105 209]]
[[106 209]]
[[107 209]]
[[108 209]]
[[109 209]]
[[110 209]]
[[111 209]]
[[112 209]]
[[113 209]]
[[114 209]]
[[115 209]]
[[116 209]]
[[117 209]]
[[118 209]]
[[119 209]]
[[120 209]]
[[121 209]]
[[122 209]]
[[123 209]]
[[124 209]]
[[125 209]]
[[126 209]]
[[127 209]]
[[128 209]]
[[129 209]]
[[130 209]]
[[131 209]]
[[132 209]]
[[133 209]]
[[134 209]]
[[135 209]]
[[136 209]]
[[137 209]]
[[138 209]]
[[139 209]]
[[140 209]]
[[141 209]]
[[142 209]]
[[143 209]]
[[144 209]]
[[145 209]]
[[146 209]]
[[147 209]]
[[148 209]]
[[149 209]]
[[150 209]]
[[151 209]]
[[152 209]]
[[153 209]]
[[154 209]]
[[155 209]]
[[156 209]]
[[157 209]]
[[158 209]]
[[159 209]]
[[160 209]]
[[161 209]]
[[162 209]]
[[163 209]]
[[164 209]]
[[165 209]]
[[166 209]]
[[167 209]]
[[168 208]]
[[169 207]]
[[169 206]]
[[170 205]]
[[171 204]]
[[171 203]]
[[172 202]]
[[172 201]]
[[173 200]]
[[174 199]]
[[174 198]]
[[175 197]]
[[175 196]]
[[176 195]]
[[176 194]]
[[177 193]]
[[178 192]]
[[178 191]]
[[179 190]]
[[179 189]]
[[180 188]]
[[181 187]]
[[181 186]]
[[182 185]]
[[182 184]]
[[183 183]]
[[183 182]]
[[184 181]]
[[184 180]]
[[185 179]]
[[186 178]]
[[186 177]]
[[187 176]]
[[187 175]]
[[188 174]]
[[189 173]]
[[189 172]]
[[190 171]]
[[190 170]]
[[191 169]]
[[191 168]]
[[192 167]]
[[193 166]]
[[193 165]]
[[194 164]]
[[194 163]]
[[195 162]]
[[196 161]]
[[196 160]]
[[197 159]]
[[197 158]]
[[198 157]]
[[198 156]]
[[199 155]]
[[199 154]]
[[200 153]]
[[201 152]]
[[201 151]]
[[202 150]]
[[202 149]]
[[203 148]]
[[204 147]]
[[204 146]]
[[205 145]]
[[205 144]]
[[206 143]]
[[206 142]]
[[207 141]]
[[208 140]]
[[208 139]]
[[209 138]]
[[209 137]]
[[210 136]]
[[211 135]]
[[211 134]]
[[212 133]]
[[212 132]]
[[213 131]]
[[213 130]]
[[214 129]]
[[214 128]]
[[215 127]]
[[216 126]]
[[216 125]]
[[217 124]]
[[217 123]]
[[218 122]]
[[219 121]]
[[219 120]]
[[220 119]]
[[220 118]]
[[221 117]]
[[221 116]]
[[222 115]]
[[222 114]]
[[223 113]]
[[223 112]]
[[223 111]]
[[222 110]]
[[222 109]]
[[221 108]]
[[221 107]]
[[220 106]]
[[220 105]]
[[219 104]]
[[219 103]]
[[218 102]]
[[217 101]]
[[217 100]]
[[216  99]]
[[216  98]]
[[215  97]]
[[214  96]]
[[214  95]]
[[213  94]]
[[213  93]]
[[212  92]]
[[212  91]]
[[211  90]]
[[210  89]]
[[210  88]]
[[209  87]]
[[209  86]]
[[208  85]]
[[208  84]]
[[207  83]]
[[206  82]]
[[206  81]]
[[205  80]]
[[205  79]]
[[204  78]]
[[204  77]]
[[203  76]]
[[202  75]]
[[202  74]]
[[201  73]]
[[201  72]]
[[200  71]]
[[199  70]]
[[199  69]]
[[198  68]]
[[198  67]]
[[197  66]]
[[197  65]]
[[196  64]]
[[196  63]]
[[195  62]]
[[194  61]]
[[194  60]]
[[193  59]]
[[193  58]]
[[192  57]]
[[191  56]]
[[191  55]]
[[190  54]]
[[190  53]]
[[189  52]]
[[189  51]]
[[188  50]]
[[187  49]]
[[187  48]]
[[186  47]]
[[186  46]]
[[185  45]]
[[184  44]]
[[184  43]]
[[183  42]]
[[183  41]]
[[182  40]]
[[182  39]]
[[181  38]]
[[180  37]]
[[180  36]]
[[179  35]]
[[179  34]]
[[178  33]]
[[178  32]]
[[177  31]]
[[176  30]]
[[176  29]]
[[175  28]]
[[175  27]]
[[174  26]]
[[174  25]]
[[173  24]]
[[172  23]]
[[172  22]]
[[171  21]]
[[171  20]]
[[170  19]]
[[169  18]]
[[169  17]]
[[168  16]]
[[167  15]]
[[166  15]]
[[165  15]]
[[164  15]]
[[163  15]]
[[162  15]]
[[161  15]]
[[160  15]]
[[159  15]]
[[158  15]]
[[157  15]]
[[156  15]]
[[155  15]]
[[154  15]]
[[153  15]]
[[152  15]]
[[151  15]]
[[150  15]]
[[149  15]]
[[148  15]]
[[147  15]]
[[146  15]]
[[145  15]]
[[144  15]]
[[143  15]]
[[142  15]]
[[141  15]]
[[140  15]]
[[139  15]]
[[138  15]]
[[137  15]]
[[136  15]]
[[135  15]]
[[134  15]]
[[133  15]]
[[132  15]]
[[131  15]]
[[130  15]]
[[129  15]]
[[128  15]]
[[127  15]]
[[126  15]]
[[125  15]]
[[124  15]]
[[123  15]]
[[122  15]]
[[121  15]]
[[120  15]]
[[119  15]]
[[118  15]]
[[117  15]]
[[116  15]]
[[115  15]]
[[114  15]]
[[113  15]]
[[112  15]]
[[111  15]]
[[110  15]]
[[109  15]]
[[108  15]]
[[107  15]]
[[106  15]]
[[105  15]]
[[104  15]]
[[103  15]]
[[102  15]]
[[101  15]]
[[100  15]]
[[99 15]]
[[98 15]]
[[97 15]]
[[96 15]]
[[95 15]]
[[94 15]]
[[93 15]]
[[92 15]]
[[91 15]]
[[90 15]]
[[89 15]]
[[88 15]]
[[87 15]]
[[86 15]]
[[85 15]]
[[84 15]]
[[83 15]]
[[82 15]]
[[81 15]]
[[80 15]]
[[79 15]]
[[78 15]]
[[77 15]]
[[76 15]]
[[75 15]]
[[74 15]]
[[73 15]]
[[72 15]]
[[71 15]]
[[70 15]]
[[69 15]]
[[68 15]]
[[67 15]]
[[66 15]]
[[65 15]]
[[64 15]]
[[63 15]]
[[62 15]]
[[61 15]]
[[60 15]]
[[59 15]]
[[58 15]]
```

Comment: Hey, this is great! I edited my post and added a different image. Do you know what algorithm will work for that? The background for that is black and white.

Comment: Threshold on blue using cv2.inRange(). Then do the same thing. That is replace the convert to gray and otsu threshold and invert to simply cv2.inRange() on blue, so that the blue turns white and the rest of the image turns black. Then get the contour, etc.

Comment: I kind of see what you are saying. Could you possibly update the code? I understand what you mean with replacing the grayscale with color inversion, but I didn't get what you mean with the cv2.inRange(). I am fairly new to OpenCV, hence, I am asking. I would highly appreciate it if you could change it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Harris Corner Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d0d/tutorial_py_features_harris.html)

Here is example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
filename = 'testimage.png'
img = cv.imread(filename)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# find Harris corners
gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
dst = cv.dilate(dst,None)
ret, dst = cv.threshold(dst,0.01*dst.max(),255,0)
dst = np.uint8(dst)
# find centroids
ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)

# define the criteria to stop and refine the corners
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 0.001)
corners = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,np.float32(centroids),(5,5),(-1,-1),criteria)

# Now draw them
res = np.hstack((centroids,corners))
print(corners)
res = np.int0(res)
img[res[:,1],res[:,0]]=[0,0,255]
# img[res[:,3],res[:,2]] = [0,255,0]
cv.imwrite('subpixel5.png',img)
```